# Partitions not being pruned in simple SparkSQL queries

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark, parquet

I'm trying to efficiently select individual partitions from a SparkSQL table (parquet in S3). However, I see evidence of Spark opening all parquet files in the table, not just those that pass the filter. This makes even small queries expensive for tables with large numbers of partitions.

Here's an illustrative example. I created a simple partitioned table on S3 using SparkSQL and a Hive metastore:

```
# Make some data
df = pandas.DataFrame({'pk': ['a']*5+['b']*5+['c']*5, 
                       'k': ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']*3, 
                       'v': range(15)})
# Convert to a SparkSQL DataFrame
sdf = hiveContext.createDataFrame(df)
# And save it
sdf.write.partitionBy('pk').saveAsTable('dataset',
                                        format='parquet',
                                        path='s3a://bucket/dataset')
```

In a subsequent session, I want to select a subset of this table:

```
dataset = hiveContext.table('dataset')
filtered_dataset = dataset.filter(dataset.pk == 'b')
print filtered_dataset.toPandas()
```

In the subsequent logs being printed, I see that pruning is *supposed* to be happening:

```
15/07/05 02:39:39 INFO DataSourceStrategy: Selected 1 partitions out of 3, pruned -200.0% partitions.
```

But then I see parquet files being opened from all partitions:

```
15/07/05 02:39:39 INFO S3AFileSystem: Reopening dataset/pk=a/part-r-00001.gz.parquet to seek to new offset 508
15/07/05 02:39:39 INFO S3AFileSystem: Actually opening file dataset/pk=a/part-r-00001.gz.parquet at pos 508
15/07/05 02:39:39 INFO S3AFileSystem: Reopening dataset/pk=b/part-r-00001.gz.parquet to seek to new offset 509
15/07/05 02:39:39 INFO S3AFileSystem: Actually opening file dataset/pk=b/part-r-00001.gz.parquet at pos 509
15/07/05 02:39:39 INFO S3AFileSystem: Reopening dataset/_common_metadata to seek to new offset 262
15/07/05 02:39:39 INFO S3AFileSystem: Actually opening file dataset/_common_metadata at pos 262
15/07/05 02:39:39 INFO S3AFileSystem: Reopening dataset/pk=c/part-r-00001.gz.parquet to seek to new offset 509
15/07/05 02:39:39 INFO S3AFileSystem: Actually opening file dataset/pk=c/part-r-00001.gz.parquet at pos 509
15/07/05 02:39:39 INFO S3AFileSystem: Reopening dataset/pk=b/part-r-00001.gz.parquet to seek to new offset -365
15/07/05 02:39:39 INFO S3AFileSystem: Actually opening file dataset/pk=b/part-r-00001.gz.parquet at pos 152
15/07/05 02:39:39 INFO S3AFileSystem: Reopening dataset/pk=a/part-r-00001.gz.parquet to seek to new offset -365
15/07/05 02:39:39 INFO S3AFileSystem: Actually opening file dataset/pk=a/part-r-00001.gz.parquet at pos 151
15/07/05 02:39:39 INFO S3AFileSystem: Reopening dataset/_common_metadata to seek to new offset -266
15/07/05 02:39:39 INFO S3AFileSystem: Actually opening file dataset/_common_metadata at pos 4
15/07/05 02:39:39 INFO S3AFileSystem: Reopening dataset/pk=c/part-r-00001.gz.parquet to seek to new offset -365
15/07/05 02:39:39 INFO S3AFileSystem: Actually opening file dataset/pk=c/part-r-00001.gz.parquet at pos 152
```

With only three partitions, this isn't a problem---but with thousands, it causes noticeable delay. Why are all these irrelevant files being opened?

Comment: Could it be related to the [SPARK-6910](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6910) issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown`, by default set to `false` because of some bugs present in the Parquet version that Spark uses.
It may be possible to use in 1.3/1.4, check the official [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#configuration).

I think this is fixed in Spark 1.5.

Comment: Yes, it turns out that performance of partitioned parquet datasets is a common source of complaint. Still some work to do, but Spark 1.5 made some big strides in this regard.