# PySpark - Hive Context Does Not Return Results but SQL Context Does for Similar Query

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I noticed a huge difference in performance when I run HiveContext versus SQLContext within PySpark for comparable queries

## VERSIONS/CONFIGURATION

- *Spark 1.3.1*(also tried *Spark 1.5.1*)
- *Hadoop 2.6* (on *CDH 5.4.0*)
- pyspark --master yarn --num-executors 5 --executor-memory 10g --driver-memory 4g --driver-cores 4

## TABLE INFORMATION

- database.table has over 2k partitions
- database.table is partitioned on field1 (used in where clause)

## HIVECONTEXT IMPLEMENTATION

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc) 
qry = "select count(*) from database.table a where a.field1 = 'ABCD'"
results = sqlContext.sql(qry).collect()
```

- Takes an indeterminate amount of time - I had to stop the execution of the query because it quickly sucked up over 50% of the system resources on the edgenode that I executed the query on.

## SQLCONTEXT IMPLEMENTATION

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.parquetFile('hdfs_path_to_hive_table/field1=ABCD/')
df.select("field2").show()
```

- Takes 6.5 seconds to execute and returns the dataframe as expected.

## QUESTIONS

- Has anyone noticed anything similar to this?
- What is happening on the backend that could be causing this consumption of resources and what could I do to avoid it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

## UPDATE 10/16/2015

I have tried:

```
SET spark.sql.hive.metastorePartitionPruning=true
```

and I was still running into the same issue. I let the process run for a little while longer to test how high the CPU usage would escalate and it reached upwards of 2000%!

I heard that parquet formatted files were potentially an issue with spark prior to version 1.5 so all of my testing with these additional settings in spark 1.5.1:

```
parquet.task.side.metadata=false
SET spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown=true
SET spark.sql.parquet.cacheMetadata=false
```

but none of them seemed to help either.

In my quest for an answer I came across these various links which led me to try the above configurations:

- **Spark reading Parquet's metastore**(parquet.task.side.metadata=false and SET spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown=true) :

  - *_https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5346*
  - *_http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31226757/partitions-not-being-pruned-in-simple-sparksql-queries*
- **Spark 1.5.1 Link to config**(SET spark.sql.parquet.cacheMetadata=false):

  - *_http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#configuration*
- **Link to a previous question that was quite similar to mine**:

  - *_https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201509.mbox/%3CCAAswR-7C0Cfduj+iaVDb-XvrnCHScrh34Lo0BadWH6XPzUXePA@mail.gmail.com%3E*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely not a difference between HiveContext/SQLContext, but instead a difference between a table where the metadata is coming from the HiveMetastore vs the SparkSQL Data Source API.  I would guess that if you create the table the same way, the performance would be similar.

In the data source API we have spent a fair amount of time optimizing the discovery and handling of many partitions, and in general I would say this path is easier to use / faster.

Likely the problem with the hive table is downloading all of the partition metadata from the metastore and converting it to our internal format.  We do this for all partitions, even though in this case you only want the first ~20 rows.

To improve performance in this case I'd try running:

`SET spark.sql.hive.metastorePartitionPruning=true`

Comment: Thanks I tried using:

    SET spark.sql.hive.metastorePartitionPruning=true

but it didn't seem to work(see above update section). A colleague of mine tried the API, but he was saying that he ran into the same issue with that as well.

Answer (score 1):

**.collect() and .show() are very different**

Perhaps the performance difference you see is due to the difference between collect (which pulls the entire resulting dataframe into the driver) and show (which by default only shows the first 20 rows of the resulting dataframe).

It seems that you're not doing any shuffling operations in the lineage, so it could be that the show is just pulling in only 20 rows (instead of the whole dataset, as in the .collect() case)

Comment: Yes that is true. But I still see an issue with performance between the HiveContext and SQLContext as well with identical queries.

Answer (score 0):

**collect()** ---> Gets all the data to edge node
**show()** ---> Will show few sample points, first 20 data points

When the data is huge, obviously you will see pretty huge difference in time and memory.